# ObjectInputStream won't initialize when using BufferedOutputStreams

Tags: java, objectoutputstream, objectinputstream, bufferedoutputstream

I am trying to send objects across a socket for a game, but they take a long time to send and can cause the game to hang. I want to use BufferedOutputStreams and BufferedInputStreams to send the data, but my ObjectInputStream won't initialize on the server side when I use the BufferedOutputStream on the client side. The weird thing is that no errors are thrown.

I'm only providing the code involved because it would take a long time to explain what's going on otherwise. Two clients are initialized each game.

```
/*Server Code*/

ObjectOutputStream toClients;//stream to both players
ObjectInputStream fromClients;//stream from both players
Socket client1;//player one socket
Socket client2;//player two socket
public RunGame(Socket client1, Socket client2)throws IOException//constructor of a new thread
{
    this.client1=client1;
    this.client2=client2;
}
public void run()//for the thread
{
    try{
        this.createGame();
        /*
         rest of code for server when running game
         */
    }
    catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
public void createGame()
{
    try{
        System.out.println("about to create");//this prints out
        fromClients=new ObjectInputStream(client1.getInputStream());//first initialization

        System.out.println("created");//this doesn't
        String s1=(String)fromClients.readObject();

        fromClients=new ObjectInputStream(client2.getInputStream());//sets input to player 2
        String s2=(String)fromClients.readObject();
    }
    catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
}

/*Client Code*/
Socket sock;//created in the constructor of the thread
ObjectOutputStream toServer;
ObjectInputStream fromServer;
public void run()
{
    try{
    System.out.println("about to create");//this prints
    toServer=new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream(),8*1024));//bufferedoutputstream is here
    toServer.writeObject("String that is to be sent to server");
    System.out.println("written");//this also prints
    }
    catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    /*
     rest of client code
     */
}
```

I've been through all of the forums but can't find anything that works, which makes me assume that I'm doing something very novice. Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to [`.flush()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#flush%28%29) your `ObjectOutputStream` otherwise the `BufferedOutputStream` won't send its output to the socket.

Comment: That was it, thanks a ton for correcting my novice-ness. You're awesome :)